# SQL / Change link with value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update all links in my MySQL table from

```
"http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/ABCDEFG/"
```

to

```
"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/ABCDEFG/".
```

What is an UPDATE SQL command for this with remaining the ABCDEFG value?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So  looks like you just need to REPLACE `http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/` with `https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/`?

Comment: Yes but how with keeping the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kind of depends on database you use; they all have similar capabilities in string manipulations, but *flavours* might (and do) differ.

For example, in Oracle, you could `replace` the first part of the string with another (`result column`) or concatenate it with the rest of the string (`result_2`).

```
SQL> select col,
  2         --
  3         replace(col, 'http://cdn.steamcommunity.com',
  4                      'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net'
  5                ) result,
  6         --
  7         'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net' ||
  8          substr(col, instr(col, '/', 1, 3)) result_2
  9  from test;

COL
------------------------------------------------------------
RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------
RESULT_2
------------------------------------------------------------
http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/ABCDEFG/
https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/ABCDEFG/
https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/ABCDEFG/


SQL>
```

As you want to *update* the table, then ... use `update`, e.g.

```
SQL> update test set
  2    col = replace(col, 'http://cdn.steamcommunity.com',
  3                       'https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net'
  4                 );

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
------------------------------------------------------------
https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/ABCDEFG/

SQL>
```